# There is no Install new module link in Admin - Modules pages - Drupal 7.x

Tags: drupal-7

There is no `Install new module` link in `Admin -> Modules` pages. In drupal 7.x versions.

Answer (score 0):

It was because when we installed Drupal, we had unchecked "check for updates automatically" in the bottom of the page, below where we entered admin username & password.

To solve this:

1. Go to the `Admin -> Modules` page.
2. Enable `Update manager` module
3. Click `Save Configuration`

When the page refreshes, you will see `Install new Module` button above the list.